# What's the key windows 2012 R2 windows service?

Tags: windows-server-2012

This may be a weird question, since our monitor tool cannot monitor the server itself, but it can monitor a windows service, so I am thinking to monitor a key windows service, to alert if that windows service is stopped. Any particular windows service falls on this category?

Thanks

Comment: Remote Procedure Call

Comment: depends on how you have set the server up to serve. for an iis server I'd monitor it. for a fileserver, the SERVER service, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pick the server or workstation service ?

Comment: I would say Server myself.